# How to get pid of last background process in SSH

Tags: bash, ssh, process, kill, background-process

My shell script is run over SSH this way:

```
ssh -i mycert.pem testuser@myserver.com <<SSHBLOCK
pm2 logs --lines 100 &
pid=$!
sleep 3
kill $pid
SSHBLOCK
```

The script works as expected when on local server (not wrapped in sshblock). But when I need to get logs on remote server, $pid is just blank. Why is $! empty when used in the SSHBLOCK above?

Comment: Hint: Where is `$!` being expanded? In the local shell, where the heredoc is created, or the remote shell, where the heredoc contents are executed? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4937792/using-variables-inside-a-bash-heredoc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must use a quote '' or escape \ to expand the variable  remotely.So,use the here document `<<'SSHBLOCK'` OR `<<\SSHBLOCK`